# How to create a method that can make class variables in python?

Tags: python

Let's say I want to make an object that has a method that adds variables to function. for example lets say I have object called obj. When i write obj.create_var("sample_variable"), I can now call obj.sample_variable. Essentially I want a method that takes the name of the variable as a parameter and creates that variable on the object. How would I write this method?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#setattr

Comment: @L-X That is completely false although a good practice.

Comment: @L-X Yeah, there's a lot of things in python that you'd think wouldn't be possible but are. See [sh](https://github.com/amoffat/sh/blob/master/sh.py#L2272) for an example of `__setattr__` used well, and [pipe](https://github.com/JulienPalard/Pipe/blob/master/pipe.py) for "no one uses bitwise or, let's use it to turn python into haskell."

Comment: I am java guy , and we don't have such thing(Or is it !) so I assume python will follow same principle But its weird why anybody want to do that

Answer (score 2):

```
def createvar(self, name, value):
    setattr(ClassName, name, value)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`setattr`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#setattr) function to set attributes on objects using string , you do not even need to create it as a separate method in your object.

Example -

```
class CA:
    pass
A()
setattr(c,'hello2','bye2')
c.hello2
>>> 'bye2'
```

If you really want it to be a method in your object, you can use same function there as well -

```
class CA:
    def varcreater(self, var, val):
            setattr(self, var, val)
c = CA()
c.varcreater('hello','bye')
c.hello
>>> 'bye'
```

If you want to set class variable, then as the first argument pass the class and not the instance, example -

```
class CA:
    def varcreater(self, var, val):
            setattr(CA, var, val)
```

Comment: I fell the the same trap, use `setattr` on the class not the instance.

Comment: why class? he wants it for instance right? He said - obj.create_var("sample_variable") and then access it as obj.sample_variable , I am hoping obj is for `object`.

Comment: Anyway added that as well to the answer, let the OP decide what he wants  :)

Answer (score 0):

```
class c(object):
    def add(self, name, value):
        # use the __class__ field
        self.__class__.name = value

# create two objects of the same type
o1 = c()
o2 = c()

# add a class variable through the first object    
o1.add("name", "value")

# it's correctly available in the second object too
print o2.name
```